# Java - GUI - Random Characters in Different Sizes, Colors

Tags: java, random, fonts, colors, font-size

Code is up and running now. Thanks for all the help from MadProgrammer. He's a baller.

Basically the main thing about this code is the Random Characters, Random Sizes, and Random Colors.

Heres the code for just that:

RANDOM COLOR:

```
int a = (int)(Math.random() * 255 - 0);
int b = (int)(Math.random() * 255 - 0);
int c = (int)(Math.random() * 255 - 0);
int z = (int)(Math.random() * 300 - 0);
Label.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(a, b, c));
```

RANDOM SIZE:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int random = (int)(Math.random() * 100000 - 50000);
Label.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.ITALIC, z));
```

RANDOM TEXT:

```
char randomChar = (char)(int)((Math.random() * 93) + 33);
Label.setText(String.valueOf(randomChar));
```

ENTIRE CODE FOR THE REAL OGs:

```
package my.dimensional;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.util.Random;
import static javafx.scene.paint.Color.color;
import static javafx.scene.text.Font.font;
import static javafx.scene.text.Font.font;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DimensionalUI extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{

    public DimensionalUI() 
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Run = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Label = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame1.getContentPane());
        jFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame1Layout);
        jFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jLabel2.setText("jLabel2");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Run.setText("Run");
        Run.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                RunActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Label.setText("BOOM");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(Label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(Run, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 247, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(Label, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 247, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 118, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(Run)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void RunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        Random rand = new Random();
        int random = (int)(Math.random() * 100000 - 50000);



        int a = (int)(Math.random() * 255 - 0);
        int b = (int)(Math.random() * 255 - 0);
        int c = (int)(Math.random() * 255 - 0);
        int z = (int)(Math.random() * 300 - 0);
        Label.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(a, b, c));
        Label.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.ITALIC, z));


        /*String[] fontNames = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
        int index = (int)(Math.random() * (fontNames.length - 1));
        String fontName = fontNames[index];
        Font font = new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, z);
        Label.setFont(new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, z));*/

        char randomChar = (char)(int)((Math.random() * 93) + 33);
        Label.setText(String.valueOf(randomChar));

    }                                   

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {

        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DimensionalUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DimensionalUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DimensionalUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DimensionalUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                new DimensionalUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel Label;
    private javax.swing.JButton Run;
    private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private void getAvailableFontFamilyNames() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `JLabel`, generate the characters, font and color and apply to the `JLabel`. See [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Comment: Okay so I switched the TextField to a JLabel, and the random integer still works. I make this code


float r = rand.nextFloat();
        float g = rand.nextFloat();
        float b = rand.nextFloat();
        Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);
        Label = randomColor;

however it doesn't work.

Comment: `JLabel#setBackground`, `JLabel#setFont`?

Comment: Thanks, I edit my code. It now has a specific Font and Color and Size. The only thing I still don't know is how to get a RANDOM font/color/size, and a RANDOM CHARACTER, since all I can do right now is integers.

Comment: Okay actually I figured out random color and size, but not font.

Comment: Color is easy, it's just three `int`s between 0 and 255. Characters could be done by using an array of predefined characters and randomizing the element index or you generate a random number between 33-126 and cast it to `char`, which will get you the ASCII equivalent `char`. Fonts could be generated by using [`GraphicsEnvironment#getAvailableFontFamilyNames()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getAvailableFontFamilyNames()), which returns a `String` array, then you just generate a random index into the array and extract the font name...

Comment: That's a valid answer, thanks. Sorry I'm a little unclear on what you mean by GraphicsEnvironment#getAvailableFontFamilyNames(). Do I just make an array of type string that is equal to that? Because NetBeans isn't recognizing that at all.

Comment: You have to get a reference to the `GraphicsEnviroment` and then call the `getAvailableFontFamilyNames` method, which returns an array of `String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Color

`Color` is just a 3 `int` values within the range of `0`-`255`...

```
int red = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
int green = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
int blue = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
Color color = new Color(red, green, blue);
```

## Character

Can could be achieved by establishing a predefined array of characters, generating a random between `0` and the array `length` and extracting the element at the specified location, personally, that's alot of tedious work.

You could load the values from a text value into a `char` array, but, again, that's a lot of work to generate the original file.

A simpler process might be to calculate a random value between `33` and `126` and convert the number to a `char`, which will provide you with the ASCII character for that value...

```
char randomChar = (char)(int)((Math.random() * 93) + 33);
```

## Font

Well, the font size is simple enough.  To get a list of available font names, you need to call [`GraphicsEnvironment#getAvailableFontFamilyNames()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getAvailableFontFamilyNames()) which will return a `String` array of font names...

```
String[] fontNames = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
```

You then simply generate a random value between `0` and array `length`...

```
int index = (int)(Math.random() * (fontNames.length - 1));
```

and extract the required font name...

```
String fontName = fontNames[index];
```

Then you create a new font...

```
Font font = new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, size);
```

Comment: I tried Label.setText(String.valueOf(randomChar)); but that wasn't recognized. Instead I tried Label.setText(Char.valueOf(randomChar)); but that didn't work either. What should I do?

Comment: `setText` expects a `String` not `char`, you'll need to convert the `char` to a `String` first. `Character.toString` should do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

To be able to randomly select from All characters, you would first have to put the characters into an array of Strings:

```
String[] chars = {0,1,2,3,4,5,a,b,c /*all characters you want to be printable*/ ,y,z};
```

Then to draw them:

```
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(chars.length + 2);  //randomly pic a number between 0 and the length of the array.
    Output.setText(chars[random]); //might have to convert to string
```

Furthermore, i would advise that you make randomGenerator a field and not a local variable as it is unneccacery to re-seed the random number generator every time the code is executed.

Comment: `randomGenerator.nextInt(chars.length + 1)` .. `1` to `chars.length + 2`?

Comment: Nice catch. i forgot it starts countng at zero. Going to correct it now.